# Count number of folders to delete in batch

Tags: batch

I need help to modify the batch script to count the number of folders to delete. I use the code to  remove those folders with yyyy-mm-dd named. And I found a similar script in the forum and try to modify it but not work.

```
@echo off
pushd %windir%\ABC\Log
set "folder=*-*-*"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /ad /o-d "%folder%"') do set "todel=%%i"
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /ad "%folder%" ^| find /c /v ""') do set "count=%%a"

For /D %%F in ("%windir%\ABC\Log\*-*-*") do rd /s /q "%%F"
pause
popd
```

[image: folder]

Answer (score 0):

Use Powershell. Try the following:

```ps
Get-ChildItem -Directory '*-*-*' | Measure-Object | Select-Object Count
```

It will return the number of folders that comply with your filter (`*-*-*`).

Comment: Hi iTwasnTme, The batch does not remove those folders. It only echoes the rmdir... commandline as your image ?